# How to vertically align (center) components in a chemical reaction?

Tags: vertical-alignment, chemfig

is there a way to somehow align the components [-M-] and the arrow so that everything is vertically centered? Thank you in advance!

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{chemfig}

\begin{document}
\setchemfig{atom sep=3em}
\schemestart
n \arrow{0}[,0]
\chemleft[
\chemfig{M([6]-R|^{+;-})}
\chemright]
\schemestop
\schemestart
\arrow{0}[,0] +  \chemfig{-[@{leftfourth,0.5},0.8]M-[@{rightfourth,0.5},0.8]}
\polymerdelim[delimiters ={[]}, height = 5pt, depth = 13pt, indice = m]{leftfourth}{rightfourth}
\schemestop
\schemestart
\arrow{->[Polymerisation][]}[0,2]
\chemfig{-[@{leftbig,0.5},1]-[@{leftmiddle,-18},0.1]M([6]-R|^{+;-})-[@{rightmiddle,42},0.1]-[@{leftsmall,0.9},1.5]M-[@{rightsmall,0.2},1]-[@{rightbig,0.1},0.3]}
\polymerdelim[delimiters ={[]}, height = 10pt, depth = 45pt, indice = k]{leftbig}{rightbig}
\polymerdelim[delimiters ={[]}, height = 1pt, depth = 11pt, indice = m]{leftsmall}{rightsmall}
\polymerdelim[delimiters ={[]}, height = 3pt, depth = 38pt, indice = n]{leftmiddle}{rightmiddle}
\schemestop


\end{document}
```

[image: Polymerisation]

Comment: FYI, once you are happy with the provided answer, you should accept that answer and thus close the question. Otherwise, people might think that the question is still open.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have removed two superfluous occurences of `\schemestop \schemestart`, replaced the `+` sign by `\+` and added an additional invisible arrow between the plus sign and the second rectant:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{chemfig}

\begin{document}

\setchemfig{atom sep=3em}
\schemestart
n \arrow{0}[,0]
\chemleft[
\chemfig{M([6]-R|^{+;-})}
\chemright]
\arrow{0}[,0] \+  \arrow{0}[,0] \chemfig{-[@{leftfourth,0.5},0.8]M-[@{rightfourth,0.5},0.8]}
\polymerdelim[delimiters ={[]}, height = 5pt, depth = 13pt, indice = m]{leftfourth}{rightfourth}
\arrow{->[Polymerisation][]}[0,2]
\chemfig{-[@{leftbig,0.5},1]-[@{leftmiddle,-18},0.1]M([6]-R|^{+;-})-[@{rightmiddle,42},0.1]-[@{leftsmall,0.9},1.5]M-[@{rightsmall,0.2},1]-[@{rightbig,0.1},0.3]}
\polymerdelim[delimiters ={[]}, height = 10pt, depth = 45pt, indice = k]{leftbig}{rightbig}
\polymerdelim[delimiters ={[]}, height = 1pt, depth = 11pt, indice = m]{leftsmall}{rightsmall}
\polymerdelim[delimiters ={[]}, height = 3pt, depth = 38pt, indice = n]{leftmiddle}{rightmiddle}
\schemestop


\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you very much. =) Appreciated your help!